# Los datos no se actualizan en xampp con ajax

Tags: java, ajax, xampp, localhost

tengo una página en la que se ingresan datos y se guardan en un json y estos mismos datos se pueden visualizar con ajax, la página la tengo en un servidor local con xampp, cuando pruebo la página localmente funciona todo correctamente, los datos se almacena, muestran y actualizan sin problema. El problema está cuando conecto un equipo distinto al servidor local, en este caso los datos si se almacenan, pero al mostrarlos ya no se actualizan. Adjunto la funcion ajax.

```js
var contador = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnMostrarDatos").click(function ()  {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            //para prueba local
            //url: "http://localhost/Ajax/datos.json",
            //para prueba en lan
            url: "http://"ip del servidor"/Ajax/datos.json",
            contentType: "JSON",
            async: true,
            success: function (data){
                var tamano = Object.keys(data).length;
                document.getElementById("nombre").innerHTML = data[contador].nombre;
                document.getElementById("correo").innerHTML = data[contador].correo;
                document.getElementById("numero").innerHTML = data[contador].numero;
                document.getElementById("direccion").innerHTML = data[contador].direccion;
                document.getElementById("contrasena").innerHTML = data[contador].contrasena;
                console.log(tamano);
                contador++
                if (contador >= tamano) {
                    tamano = Object.keys(data).length;
                    contador = 0;
                }
                
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

En este caso cuando utilizo la linea url: "http://"ip del servidor"/Ajax/datos.json", con la ip del servidor, si accede a los datos pero no los actualiza cuando ingreso uno nuevo.

Comment: puede que este quedando en cache la url por ser .json y esta no se este refrescando con los datos.

Comment: A ver, no tiene ningún sentido lo que estás haciendo aquí. Ajax existe para comunicar entre cliente y servidor, y el intermediario de esa comunicación es el archivo que pones en el parámetro `url` de la petición Ajax. Si ahí pones un archivo `.json` no tiene sentido, ahí debe haber un archivo de servidor (con extensión `.php` para este caso) y si quieres mandar datos, los pones en el parámetro `data` de la petición Ajax.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, @A.Cedano Lo pude solucionar con otro archivo PHP.